# Load users environment variables in a cronjob

Tags: ubuntu, bash, cron, environment-variables

How can I load the users environment variables in a cronjob?

---

I have a cronjob which should start a script every minute on my Ubuntu machine:

```
* * * * * /home/user/myscript.sh;
```

In this script I want to use environment variables like `$JAVA_HOME` and `$M2_HOME` to automatically start a build process. The problem is that those variables are set in the `.bashrc` via `export JAVA_HOME=/../..`.

Therefore I `source` these files before executing my script:

```
* * * * * source ~/.bash_profile; source ~/.bashrc; /home/user/myscript.sh;
```

However, the variables aren't set! To test this I `echo` the environment variables via `env` to a log file:

```
env >> ~/env.log
echo $M2_HOME >> ~/env.log
```

The log file still doesn't contain the variables. Only the following are appended to the file (no `$M2_HOME` etc.):

```
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
HOME=/home/user
LOGNAME=user
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/home/user
```

If I run the script right in my shell all of the variables are print out to `env.log`.

The same happens when I put the `source` commands into the script file. Only if I remove the `export` keyword before the declaration of the variable it is visible by the `echo $var` command. But this is not a solution because I don't manage these declarations.

---

I tried the solution of @tripplee with the limited sh shell problem, but it still doesn't work. I further reduced it to a very simple cronjob without a second script to show the problematic:

```
* * * * * . $HOME/.bash_profile; . $HOME/.bashrc; env > $HOME/env.log;
```

`cat /home/user/env.log`:

```
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
HOME=/home/user
LOGNAME=user
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/home/user
```

Comment: Take a look in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557777/crontab-job-does-not-get-the-environment-variables-set-in-bashrc-file

Answer (score 4):

The cron job syntax is restricted to `sh` only so you cannot use Bashisms like `~`.  Fortunately, the fix is easy -- just replace it with `$HOME`.  Similarly, `source` needs to be replaced with `.` (just a dot).

Of course, the scripts you source mustn't use Bash syntax either if you intend to use them from `sh`.  Probably the easiest fix is to migrate these things to your script (or create a wrapper script for Cron to run).

Because inside your script, you can use `bash` if you like, provided of course that the shebang line is correctly `#!/bin/bash` (adjust the path if you have to) rather than `#!/bin/sh`.

If you don't like that for some reason, you can inline Bash in your `crontab` file by specifying it explicitly:

```
* * * * * bash -c 'source ~/.bash_profile; source ~/.bashrc; ./myscript.sh'
```

You should be able to see `source: command not found` and `export: command not found` in the emails sent by `cron` when things go wrong.  Examining the error output is really important for troubleshooting.

Of course, if you have the standard `.bashrc` on Ubuntu, it will bail out immediately if you try to source it from a noninteractive script.  Maybe better then to put the settings you want in a noninteractive use in another file (maybe `.profile` which will be read by `sh` by default)?

Comment: That is usefull. Though, the result is still the same. I updated the question.

Comment: You forgot to fix the `source: command not found` error. Sorry about not mentioning it in my very initial answer.

Comment: And I'm sorry to tell you that this doesn't work either. Same result. But thx for the hint! I updated the question again.

Comment: Oh, if the Bash start-up files contain Bash-only syntax, that won't work either -- you'll get `export: command not found` instead.  Better really to put these in a Bash script and call that from Cron.  Updated answer.

Comment: Still doesn't work! :/

Comment: Added stuff from http://stackoverflow.com/a/15574078/874188 -- thanks @FedericoSierra.

Comment: The problem was a different one (too). I added an answer: http://serverfault.com/a/673498/98187

Answer (score 4):

To add on to tripleee's answer, you can cause all of your crons to be evaluated in bash (or the shell of your choice) by specifying the shell in the crontab.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
* * * * * . $HOME/.bash_profile; . $HOME/.bashrc; env > $HOME/env.log;
```

*edit* and if you really want to see what it's doing, the following command should make it sufficiently verbose:

```
/bin/bash -x -c '. $HOME/.bash_profile; . $HOME/.bashrc; env > $HOME/env.log' > /tmp/cron.`date +\%s`
```

`set -x` or the -x flag on the commandline will cause most shells to print every line evaluated.

To test on the commandline remove the \ from the date command. This is needed to prevent cron from evaluating %s as standard input.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a [full tty in cron](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109552). But if you run it via `sudo -i` you'll get one.

```
* * * * * sudo -u user -i bash -c '. $HOME/.bash_profile; . $HOME/.bashrc; env > $HOME/env.log;'
```

Or to start the script:

```
* * * * * sudo -u user -i bash -c '. $HOME/.bash_profile; . $HOME/.bashrc; /home/user/myscript.sh;'
```

If you put the `source` commands in a **Bash** script which starts the target script you'll get a neat:

```
* * * * * sudo -u user -i /home/user/mystarter.sh;
```

Comment: This post is partly based on http://serverfault.com/a/673487/98187

Comment: If that's the case, then Federico Sierra's comment would have worked for you. The problem is the interactive shell detection is causing your profile to short-circuit out before it gets to the export statements.